# c++ hex number format

Tags: c++, hex

I'm trying to output the hex value of a char and format it in a nice way.

Required:          `0x01 : value 0x1`

All I can get is:  `00x1 : value 0x1`        // or 0x1 if i don't use iomanip

Here's the code i have, 'ch' was declared to be a unsigned char. Is there any other way to do it other than checking the value and manually add an '0'??

```
cout << showbase;
cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int) ch;
```

Edit:

I found one solution online:

```
cout << internal << setw(4) << setfill('0') << hex << (int) ch
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
std::cout << "0x" << std::noshowbase << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)ch;
```

Since `setw` pads out to the left of the overall printed number (after `showbase` is applied), `showbase` isn't usable in your case. Instead, manually print out the base as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In one on my projects I did this:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, byte value)
{
     stream << "0x" << hex << (int)value;
     return stream;
}
```

I surchaged the operator<< for stream output, and anything that was a byte was shown in hexadecimal. byte is a typedef for unsigned char.